# C# WPF items into string form Foreach list

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach

I have a Click function that starts up a program with the selected arguments

```
private void Launch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 //start up proccess here

 Process.StartInfo.Arguments = app + app_output + nosplash + showscripterrors;

 etc...

 }
```

works fine but for the string app_output is a foreach statement using the code below. The problem is that only the last foreach item is being set in the argument. I basically want the app_string to be itemA;itemB;itemC etc...

```
string app_string = "0";
string app_output = "0";
foreach (var item in TheList)
{
 //item.PropertyChanged += TheList_Item_PropertyChanged;
 if (item.IsSelected == true)
{
app_string = item.TheText;
app_output = app_string + ";";
}
else
{
//System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("no item selected");
}
}
```

how would i go about getting the app_output to render the foreach items? Shout i enter the foreach into an array?

Ive tried placing the foreach code within the argument string but does not allow foreach method inside it.

Comment: You are overwriting app_output with a new value in each iteration... app_output += app_string + ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is using a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(var item in TheList)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0};",item);
        }

        string app_ouput = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

use it:

```
string line = string.Join(";", TheList.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.TheText));
```

> ### String.Join Method
>
> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx